# Spring constant with newton and energy-conversation

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation

Figure 1 : In before part have mass $m$ not moving then $x=0$ ,When the object is at lowest point the object will be in equilibrium, $v=0$ and object move down $x$

---

To find the spring constant suppose a body of mass $m$ is on a spring with the spring constant $k$
I have 2 method to find spring constant

1. From the object in the equilibrium state so $F=kx$ that is $mg=kx$ thus $k=\frac{mg}{x}$
2. Use energy conversation : $mgx=\frac{1}{2}kx^2$ thus $k=\frac{2mg}{x}$

> Question is why k in 1. and 2. not equal? What did I do wrong?

[image: figure 1]

Comment: There are two different $x$ s. The equilibrium $x$ is where the mass will hang unmoving, halfway between the top and the bottom (the other $x$) of the mass's up and down movement.

Comment: I get it. thank you

Comment: I have reposted this as an answer.

Comment: Duplicate? - [Getting 2 different answers when finding spring constant k
when gravity is involved](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/336702/getting-2-different-answers-when-finding-spring-constant-k-when-gravity-is-inv/336710#336710)

Comment: Oh thank you, sorry I dont know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two different $x$ s. The equilibrium $x$ is where the mass will hang unmoving, halfway between the top and the bottom (the other $x$) of the mass's up and down movement.